# Nuxt 3 - useFetch on a resource from the public folder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to access data for dynamic routes during the setup phase. As dynamic import through vite doesn't seem to work no matter what tricks I try it doesn't seem to work so, as a workaround, I decoded to put all those assets in the `public` folder and simply call them with the useFetch. Unfortunately, for some reason the router can't locate them at that phase. If I simply use native fetch in the `mounted` function, they are indeed returned with no problem. Is there any way around this problem or do I need to rethink the structure again?

Minimal reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/min-nuxt-usefetch-public-cveew0 - as you can see, the console prints out `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/text.txt"` despite the text.txt being reachable through the browser.